# What happens if you try to update a locked record in JET?

Tags: ms-access, dao, jet, rowlocking, database-locking

If I use JET/DAO to open a recordset on a MDB database using `dbPessimistic` locking, what will happen if another user tries to update a row in that recordset at that time?  Will there be an error, or will JET/DAO keep trying until the row is unlocked?

Comment: That should be relatively simple to mock up, have you tried it?

Comment: The best and easiest way to find out would be to try it.